# Why do we always extend Exception class and not RuntimeEexception class?

Tags: java, exception

I think we generally extend the Exception class only beacause we don't want to bother about whether an exception should be made checked or unchecked. Am I right?

I asked another question related to this and here is the link for my questions and the answers I got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169866/while-creating-my-own-exception-when-should-i-extend-exception-class-and-when-sh 
But I still have one confusion i.e. I think we generally extend the Exception class only beacause we don't want to bother about whether an exception should be made checked or unchecked. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the only reason to extend Exception instead of RuntimeException is to make it checked.

There might be some special case where you do want to throw an unchecked exception, but mostly when you throw an exception you do it because you want the calling method to be able to recover if the exception is thrown so you almost always want to use the checked exception. 
Quite often you also use your own exceptions to wrap around lower level exceptions in your program to make a looser coupling, i.e. convert a SQLException into a custom DatastoreException so you can later exchange the SQL server for another technology.

So we extend Exception to make it checked, but I do not necessary think you should blindly always extend Exception, but instead consider if the exception you need maybe is a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at some of the frameworks in use today such as Spring, you will see it advocates the usage of Runtime Exceptions. Generally you will use Runtime exceptions when catching a certain exception makes no sense to the calling party since they cannot do anything about that exception. Hence you leave it at the discretion of the calling party to handle it if they require. But if you do use the Exception class rather than the RuntimeException class, then the calling party needs to handle these exceptions even though they do not need to, since by specification these are classified as checked exceptions.